# MassTransit sqs transport local development error

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit, localstack

I am using MassTransit's sqs transport. On a real aws sqs setup everything works great. However, when developing locally using localstack I run into the following error.

```
MassTransit.Messages[0]
      R-FAULT amazonsqs://us-east-1/UpdateName f28f6a22-f0dd-4ffa-926f-2b8c871c8bf0 Value cannot be null.
      Parameter name: source
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: An exception occurred while deserializing the message envelope ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MassTransit.Serialization.JsonConsumeContext..ctor(JsonSerializer deserializer, IObjectTypeDeserializer objectTypeDeserializer, ReceiveContext receiveContext, MessageEnvelope envelope)
   at MassTransit.Serialization.JsonMessageDeserializer.MassTransit.IMessageDeserializer.Deserialize(ReceiveContext receiveContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MassTransit.Serialization.JsonMessageDeserializer.MassTransit.IMessageDeserializer.Deserialize(ReceiveContext receiveContext)
   at MassTransit.Serialization.SupportedMessageDeserializers.Deserialize(ReceiveContext receiveContext)
   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
   at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
dbug: MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter<MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Topology.ErrorSettings>
```

This is only a problem with the latest MassTransit (5.5.1), but in version 5.3.0 it works fine.

Any help to fix this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider to send proper event message structure? Similar to this: https://medium.com/@mstrYoda/how-to-consume-messages-from-java-applications-with-rabbitmq-in-masstransit-e5c96b6618dd ?

Comment: @DorianW.that example uses RabbitMQ